# Searching for real biological neuron firing data [numeric]

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, neural-network, data

I am searching for real neuron firing data, so I can look at each neuron for fire timing (frequency) and incoming/outgoing signal-strength. I already found short youtube videos of [real neuron firing footage (measured via calcium)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yy994HpFudc), but I am searching for numeric data.

**Data-Requirements**

- Region is not important
- the longer time range, the better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website [crcns.org](http://crcns.org/data-sets) hosts open source data recorded from neurons in various brain areas.